# Erro de "Invalid App Id" em botão de "Like" Facebook

Tags: jquery, c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

Estou fazendo um blog e estou colocando o botão de *like*.
O código que estou usando é:

Este está no começo da página:

```
<script>    
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

E para colocar o botão faço assim:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="@String.Format("{0}/{1}", "/Blog/Artigo", @item.ArtigoID)" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Olhando o console do Google Chrome, vejo 2 alertas, quando não estou logado no Facebook que são:

```
Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. all.js:53
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init(). all.js:53
```

Porque isto acontece?
O que devo estar fazendo de errado?
Existe alguma forma de não usar o JS do Facebook e fazer algo que abra um modal para o usuário fazer o *like*? Pois para pegar o total de *like* tem, mas para dar *like* eu não achei.

Answer (score 0):

Falta o `App Id`. Veja esta linha aqui:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

Ela tem que ser assim:

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=SeuAppIdDe16Dígitos";
```

Comment: Procurei o meu app id é de 15 posições. Quando mudei passou a ter este erro: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
O URL informado não é permitido pela configuração do aplicativo.: Uma ou mais das URLs fornecidas não são permitidas nas configurações do aplicativo. A URL deve corresponder à URL do site ou URL do Canvas, ou o domínio deve ser um subdomínio de um dos domínios do aplicativo. Usei a url https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ para ver o app id

Comment: Já fui no endereço https://developers.facebook.com/apps/168583496535883/settings/ e no App Domains coloquei o dominio www.sesmt.org e nada...Estou tentando achar a solução...